# Android OS documentation

Tags: documentation

Is there documentation that explains all OS processes, file systems, and other folders (for instance `/dev` and related file device) in Android OS? I’m interested to discover all this information regarding Pixel 3a XL with Android 8.

Answer (score 0):

https://source.android.com/docs would be great start, but you need to invest time to look for what you need.